# Am I describing the time events using the right grammar?

Tags: spoken-english

Am I describing the time events using the right grammar?

> After finishing the 5 days of the IV steroids course, I started to
>   regain most of my vision within one week (large blind spot). The rest
>   of my vision (brightness) took up to 6 months to be recovered.

I couldn't talk about the 20 to 30 days where symptoms gradually started. Maybe I couldn't mention that the 6 months are the time event that right (immediately) followed the one week of recovery.

Here's the sequence (series of events followed by each other):

1. Symptoms started and getting worse for 10 to 15 days.
2. I started to go to doctors and do tests for another 10 to 15 days. Symptoms are still getting worse during this period.
3. I started receiving a treatment for 5 days.
4. I started improving within one week (80%).
5. It took up to 5 or 6 months to completely recover.

How can I rephrase my words to do it without writing this sequence of events in points? I need to use conjunctions and words like (after, before, ago, last, the following...etc.) and I want to use the correct grammar (present perfect, past, past perfect...etc.) to be able to say it like a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original paragraph:

> After finishing the 5 days of the IV steroids course, I started to regain most of my vision within one week (large blind spot). The rest of my vision (brightness) took up to 6 months to be recovered.

New suggestions:

Sentence 1:

> Within a week after finishing the five-day IV steroids course, I started to regain most of my vision, although there was still a large blind spot.

Sentence 2, multiple choices.

2a:

> The rest of my vision made a full recovery over the next six months.

2b:

> Over the next six months, the rest of my vision made a full recovery.

2c:

> The rest of my vision recovered over the following six months.

2d:

> Over the following six months, the rest of my vision recovered.